# How to modify SDP in order to receive video?

Tags: webrtc

Previously, when creating a peerconnection it was possible to set offerToReceiveVideo to true, but that API was deprecated. How should I setup audio -> audio+video call now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found constraints, that resulted in sdp with recvonly video [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sip_js/offertoreceivevideo%7Csort:date/sip_js/xL7wIUwt8JA/aWnqRRlaAQAJ):

```
{
  optional: [], 
  // Chrome 

  mandatory: { 
    'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 
    'OfferToReceiveVideo': true 
  }, 
  // Firefox 
  'offerToReceiveAudio': true, 
  'offerToReceiveVideo': true
}
```

However in my case remote videostream was still absent.

There is a better solution for "audio" to "audio + video" calls:

- create a canvas dom element, fill it with blackness,
- get stream from canvas,
- put track from this stream to stream with audio
- create peerconnection

It will look something like this:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.rect(0, 0, 640, 480);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();
const canvasStream = canvas.captureStream(0);
mediaStream.addTrack(canvasStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
```

This way it's easier to enable actual videostream and you can use `replaceTrack()`